Information on JT86MB triac please
I'm fixing a pedestal fan after the motor suddenly stopped. There's a typical dimmer circuit board in series with the motor, but I am unable to find anything about the triac on it
It's a JT86MB
When searching I only find Chinese sources, nothing about it in English. I tried several variations like removing MB or JT and so forth. Still nothing.
Does anyone know which Western triac this is an equivalent for? Is it like a BT136
Also, does anyone know if this a new Chinese trend now? Renaming components so we can't find datasheets for them?

The Chinese tend to loot from very old circuit boards and resell these very old parts (and also counterfeits) so it's not unusual that you're getting nothing but results from AliExpress or whatever. This part is likely very old so I think it would be difficult to find an exact replacement.

Difficult to give an equivalent's name but I think, based on the wattage info of the equipment, a suitable SCR can be directly used. I don't think the circuit is too much different than a typical dimmer. So a 600V/4A or 600V/8A SCR would do, I believe.

There are a great many (many hundreds) of independent semiconductor companies in China and some of them sell primarily to domestic OEMs so there is little incentive to put their data online, even in Chinese, let alone in foreign languages.
I believe this part is (or was) made by Jiangsu JieJie Microelectronics (捷捷微电专业), located in the eponymous province (population about 85 million). One of the older companies (1995).
I don't see data on their website for this part, or even series, but the logo of photos online matches (you didn't supply a photo, which you should do for parts ID).

You can try a generic triac in a similar package. Something like a 16A 600V triac BTA16-600BWRG. Chances are it is similar to other triacs, including the pinout, but it would be prudent to trace the circuit and check the latter.
More company data from here:

Founded in 1995, Jiangsu JieJie Microelectronics Co., Ltd. is a
high-tech enterprise mainly engaged in designing,manufacturing and
marketing semiconductor discrete components and power electronic
devices.We are the first company to produce “square” type SCR and
TRIAC and have the most extensive SCR and TRIAC production line in
China.
JieJie occupies a floor area of 83958 square meters,including a clean
workshop area of 27907 square meters. With total assets over 65
million USD and about 500 employee, of whom more than 12% are R&D
engineers, with continuous high-intensity R&D investment (about 4% of
our sales revenue ),we have independent development ability and
intellectual property rights. Our products have their structure
characteristics and unique technology.

